# Architecture specific headers

Tags: c

I have a project that targets multiple different architectures. For example, I have a header file 'fpr.h' that deals with floating point registers. These headers exist in:

```
arch/amd64/fpr.h
arch/ppc32/fpr.h
...
```

I have an architecture dependent file 'foo.c' that needs to include fpr.h. 
Obviously, I only want the header for the target architecture to be included but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I'm trying to use autotools for my build system but I don't see any suggested way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to let the autoconf script detect the architecture and set up a symlink `arch/target` that points to the right directory of architecture-specific headers, then `#include <arch/target/fpr.h>`. Making this work with out-of-place builds may be tricky, though.

Another way to do this is to set up an `arch/target` directory by hand and populate it with files like `fpr.h.in` that get preprocessed by M4 to refer to the actual architecture-specific header.

Answer (score 1):

Have autotools set a build define.

Have the C files rewritten to include the correct header depending on the setting of the define

```
#ifdef HAVE_PPC_FPR_H
  #include <arch/ppc32/fpr.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_AMD64_FPR_H
  #include <arch/amd64/fpr.h>
#endif
```

You can use AC_CHECK_HEADER multiple times in autoconf to detect each header file, but remember to omit writing a failure in the "action if not found" section.  In the "action if found" section, it is advisable to not only set the necessary define, but to also set a define that the floating point header was found.  That way you can embed after your checks a test to see if FPR_FOUND is not set, which you could then use to fail the configuration before the building actually starts.

Comment: This isn't quite right. I should have all the headers, its a matter of which one to include.

Comment: Well, then forget the AC_CHECK_HEADER and set an AC_ARG to capture the command line selection at ./configure time.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the C preprocessor:

```
#define PP_STRINGIZE_(x)      #x
#define PP_STRINGIZE(x)       PP_STRINGIZE_(x)

#define ARCH_HEADER(h)        PP_STRINGIZE(arch/ARCH/h)

#include ARCH_HEADER(fpr.h)
```

You can provide the `ARCH` definition on compiler command line:

```
gcc -DARCH="amd64" foo.c
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to put all of the architecture-specific headers in architecture-specific directories, and then select the appropriate directory based on the architecture to put on your include search path.